# how to highlight words using start and end postiton

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using below code to get and store start and end position of words now I want to highlight that words while refresh page.. how to do it.

```
function getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(element) 
{

var start = 0, end = 0;
var sel, range, priorRange;

if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    priorRange = range.cloneRange();
    priorRange.selectNodeContents(element[0]);
    priorRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
    start = priorRange.toString().trim().length;
    end = start + range.toString().length;
} else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
    (sel = document.selection).type != "Control") {
    range = sel.createRange();
    priorRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    priorRange.moveToElementText(element);
    priorRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
    start = priorRange.text.length;
    end = start + range.text.length;
}
return {
    start: start,
    end: end
  };
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with php or wordpress?

Comment: in wordpress...

Comment: This is a javascript function with no reference to php or wordpress

Comment: start and end variable value stored in database...and it will available for me...but thing this that how to select words with that postions